Unity3d Fields serialization rule
Is it possible to change default unity monobehaviour’s field serialization rule? I need to serialize fields if they have my custom attribute.
I can add ‍[NonSerialized]‍ attribute, but  I want to do that automatically.
I tried to implement ISerializationCallbackReceiver, but I couldn’t get access to SerializableObject to remove this fields  automaticaly.

What is the desired result? I cannot imagine, tbh, why someone even needs to make a copy of the SerializedField attribute

I have data component with public fields. And I wrote custom Editor which draw only fields with my attribute.
It works great. But all my public fields assigned runtime (exclude fields with custom attribute which assigned from editor). So in this case I don’t need to save them by unity serialization.

I think replacing the fields with properties can do the trick then.

could you post a [mcve]? Currently it is a bit hard to understand what exactly your use case is and what the desired outcome
